# How to handle business logic errors and application exceptions from business logic layer in MVC ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC application in which I need to trap errors in business logic classes and redirect to error controller. I need to trap both errors, ones which are related to my business logic and others which are application exceptions. If I throw an exception from my business logic, how do I catch that in the current controller and how do I redirect to ErrorController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decorate your Controller/Action with the `[HandleErrorAttribute]` to do just that.

For example:

```
    [HandleError]
    public ActionResult PlaceOrder(OrderDetails orderDetails)
    {
        orderService.PlaceOrder(orderDetails);
        return View("Success");
    }
```

You can set the appropriate `View` to load to depend on the `Exception Type`:

```
    [HandleError(ExceptionType=typeof(PlaceOrderException),View="OrdersError"]
    [HandleError(ExceptionType=typeof(Exception),View="GeneralError"]
    public ActionResult PlaceOrder(OrderDetails orderDetails)
    {
        orderService.PlaceOrder(orderDetails);
        return View("Success");
    }
```

Alternatively, you can register it globally on your `global.asax`:

```
    GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute
    {
        View = "Error"
    });
```

P.S: The above example assumes your 'Error/GeneralError/OrdersError' `Views` are in the `Shared` folder. if they're not, you're gonna need to specify the full path.

**Edit (as per your comment):**

If you want to return `Json` instead of `View`, create the following `ActionFilter`:

```
public class HandleErrorJsonAttribute : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

        filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
        {
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
            ContentType = "application/json",
            Data = new 
            {
                Msg = "An Error Occured",
                ExceptionMsg = filterContext.Exception.ToString()
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Then use the new `[HandleErrorJson]` attribute (as outlined above), or register it as a Global Filter in your `global.asax`.

Comment: haim770 thanks for your reply. My application is single page so I have only one view. I want to send error details like msg:An error occured.. etc in Json format to my Index view and from there I want to display this error information in an appropriate format.

Comment: I revised my answer accordingly.

Comment: haim770, it's not working for me. I give you sample of what Im doing:

[HandleErrorJson]
 public JsonResult testControler()
{
some code here
call to business logic class
in business logic I check if there are any business related validation errors, if yes I want to send the error message to my client(JS code) in json format

}

Comment: when error occurs it seems to execute your OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext) method in HandleErrorJsonAttribute class, but does not send the formed json to view(Index in my case)

Comment: You want to return a Json result or a View result with the Exception details embedded somewhere in the view? set it in the `ViewBag` automatically?

Comment: I want to return a Json result which I will handle on client side to display error message in a desired format.

Comment: Then my `HandleErrorJson` should do it. did you actually throw an Exception from the `Action` you tried?

Comment: yes I threw the exception and it comes to your function OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext) but it does not send anything to client. I don't know whatelse Im missing to make it run

Answer (score -1):

I think it is a good idea to look at this sample. When ever an error occurs in Business logic layer you can return false or say -1 for a method of Business class, then show proper error message to user, and in catch part of the business method you can use one of popular error logging libs like Log4NET or elmah.

Edited:
To redirect user when error occurs you can specify the error controller in custom error section of web config

Comment: Thanks Persian Dev(Sepasgozaram !) The above answer by ham770 solved my issue. What I needed is throw a validation error or application exception in BLL and send Json response with error/exceptions details to client. At client I want to handle the incoming json response and display error in a desired format.